# Introduce Generics into legacy code and iteration over parameterized instances

Tags: java, generics

my questions relates to introducing Generics into legacy Java classes.
The legacy classes from the code below that I want to generify are ClientObjectProxy and ClientObjectContainer. ClientObject remains unchanged.
For simplicity I put all the classes into one outer class.

Now in the legacy code there are many calls  of the method ClientObjectProxyContainer.getProxies() on ClientObjectProxyContainer instances that are not parameterized.

By introducing Generics existing code like in Loop 4 won't compile anymore, the call needs to be extracted to a local variable like in Loop 1 or a declaration with a question mark needs to be used similar to Loop 2.
New code should use parameterized variables like in Loop 3.

My question is, is this is the way to go for me, change the existing code to either Loop 1 or Loop 2, or is there's a way of not modifying legacy code?

Thanks

Jan

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GenericForumsExample {
    /**
     * This class is unchanged
     */
    private class ClientObject {
    }

    /**
     * @param <T> Type of the ClientObject behind this proxy
     */
    private class ClientObjectProxy<T extends ClientObject> {
    }

    /**
     * @param <T> Type of the ClientObject contained in this collection
     */
    private class ClientObjectProxyContainer<T extends ClientObject> {
        //Previous signature was:
        //  public List<ClientObjectProxy> getProxies(){
        // New signature is the following
        public List<ClientObjectProxy<T>> getProxies(){
            return new ArrayList<ClientObjectProxy<T>>();
        }
    }

    public void testScenario() {
        ClientObjectProxyContainer proxyContainer = new ClientObjectProxyContainer();
        List<ClientObjectProxy> proxies = proxyContainer.getProxies(); // Just a compiler warning

        // Loop 1
        for (ClientObjectProxy proxy : proxies) {                     // Compiler OK
            //Do something...
        }

        // Loop 2
        ClientObjectProxyContainer<?> clientObjectProxyContainer = new ClientObjectProxyContainer();
        for (ClientObjectProxy<?> proxy : clientObjectProxyContainer.getProxies()) {
            //Do something...
        }

        // Loop 3
        for (ClientObjectProxy<ClientObject> proxy : new ClientObjectProxyContainer<ClientObject>().getProxies()) {
            //Do something...
        }

        // Loop 4
        // Compiler fails on next code line
        // incompatible types
        // found   : java.lang.Object
        // required: GenericForumsExample.ClientObjectProxy
        for (ClientObjectProxy proxy : proxyContainer.getProxies()) {
            //Do something...
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How could Loop 4 ever work in legacy code? Without generics that's impossible.

Comment: The previous signature of getProxies() was:
`public List<ClientObjectProxy> getProxies(){
        ...
    }`
So the returned List was parameterized, but the Proxy itself was not

Comment: It would be good to edit your question in order to make this point clear. I think it is a very important point when thinking about solutions.

Comment: Now that we have this clear, I notice that none of your variants actually makes use of the type parameter to ClientObjectProxy. Your legacy loop example looks exactly the same as the three others.

Comment: Thanks @MarkoTopolnik just added the previous signature as inline comment

Comment: ...and added Type parameters to the loop variables in Loop 2 and Loop 3. Generics really confused me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In code dealing with generics, try to avoid using raw types at all. When you use these types, you will often loose more type-information than you expect, as is happening in this case.

The call `proxyContainer.getProxies()` in the last loop returns actually a `List` (because `proxyContainer` is of a raw type, all generics relating to its type are removed, including generics in method signatures). And if you iterate over a raw `List`, you will only get `Object`s out of it, so there is a compile error. You can resolve this by writing `(List<ClientObjectProxy>)proxyContainer.getProxies()` in the for loop (you will get a warning of course).

Thus it is usually clearer to use wildcards instead of raw types. In code which is already "genericified", never use the raw type `ClientObjectProxyContainer`, but always `ClientObjectProxyContainer<?>`, if you don't have a concrete type. This type has basically the same meaning, but it will not lead to all generic types being ignored when it is used.

When using the wildcard for the type of `proxyContainer`, the result type of `getProxies()` will be `List<ClientProxyObject<?>>` instead of just `List`, so you can take `ClientProxyObject`s out of it (but here, too, prefer to use `ClientProxyObject<?>`!).

Answer (score 0):

I prefer Loop 1 approach if you introduce the Generics.Then you do not have worry about the type checking.